# How do I run a media server?

Tags: media, media-server

I want to be able to serve files from my external hard drive through my Raspberry Pi to my network. Essentially using the Raspberry Pi as a network interface for my External Hard Drive, and allowing my other devices (game consoles, tablets, PCs, etc) to access the media there.

I like the interface and flexibility of Windows Media Center, but I suppose that's probably a no-go here.

Comment: This is a bit subjective...

Comment: @Jivings In what way?

Comment: Because it depends on ones preference of media center. Personally I use Samba to share files and OMXPlayer to play them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)?

There are two distros being developed for the Pi. These are:

- [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/news/item/241-openelec-meets-raspberry-pi-part-1)
- [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/2012/05/raspbmc-is-now-in-beta/)
- [XBian](http://xbian.org/)

Your other choice is to perform connectivity and media playback manually.
This involves using a Samba for file sharing and OMXPlayer for your media.

My new personal favorite is XBian, which is well supported, up-to-date, and offers a selection of useful utilities pre-installed such as Transmission and Sickbeard.